# Jooq convert subset of selected columns to entity

Tags: java, jooq

If I have two tables with a simple many-to-one relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE child (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  parent_id BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES parent (id)
)
```

How can I query on the child table and convert the rows corresponding to the parent table to a Java Record easily with Jooq?

```java
    var a = dslContext.select(
        PARENT.ID,
        PARENT.NAME,
        DSL.field(DSL.row(
            PARENT.child().ID,
            PARENT.child().NAME)
            .convert(???)) // How can I convert sub-entities like this?
        .fetch(Records.mapping(ChildDTO::new)); // This works fine for the top-level
```

It seems like something along those lines ^ should work, but I haven't been able to find it. Am I on the right track, or is there another approach I should be taking?

Comment: Before I answer, can you confirm you want to navigate things from parent to child (one-to-many)? Or did you really intend to navigate your data from child to parent (many-to-one)?

Comment: Confirmed - I do want to navigate from child to parent. I want to display a list view of the children, but in each row show the name of the parent object. The entities I'm dealing with are more complex, and I have multiple of these relationships. So I would like to convert the parent(s) individually rather than dealing with a single massive record with all the fields together, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's just a problem of reversed relationships here, where child and parent were confused. This should work?

```java
dslContext
    .select(
        CHILD.ID,
        CHILD.NAME,
        row(CHILD.parent().ID, CHILD.parent().NAME).mapping(ParentDTO::new))
    .from(CHILD)
    .fetch(Records.mapping(ChildDTO::new))
```

THis example is using [`Row2.mapping(Function2)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Row2.html#mapping(org.jooq.Function2)), which is just convenience for an [ad-hoc converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) placed on the `Row2` expression, which is a `SelectField<Record2<T1, T2>>` (there's no need to wrap it in `DSL.field(...)`, explicitly)

Comment: Yeah, that's great! The examples I found had that extra `field` call that threw me off. The relationship makes sense when you see the real domain entities, but I wanted to keep it as generic as possible here :)